# visibility in list views

Tags: eclipse, list-view, migration

we're trying to migrate one org to another one but we are encountering some problems in list views for all objects. The visibility is not maintained.

We are using Eclipse Deployment to Server to migrate the metadata.

Is there any way to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think we can not migrate visiblity settings yet.
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZZTlAAO
Kindly Vote Up for this Idea.